# Reset a class instance to its previous state in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, oop

I am working on a application, that read a xml file and create and init classes based on xml data.
when needed classes create UIViews based on their variables and send that to parent classes.

The hierarchy of classes is something like this: book -> page -> layer -> character -> part

I need pages reset and recreate themselves every time need to be shown but it is not possible because the inner classes like layers and character have been changed (the books are interactives)

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just reverting to a previous state, then start with [Undo Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/UndoArchitecture.html).

When you're presenting a new object graph, it's usually easiest to initialize a new object graph rather than convert one graph to another representation.